# How do I get the string out of an ObjectID to use as URL slug?

Tags: mongodb, tornado, pymongo

Newbie here. I'm using Tornado and PyMongo and I'm trying to get the string out of an ObjectId so I can do this:

```
<p><a href="/edit/{{ **object ID string** }}">Edit</a></p>
```

from

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "50c26c91efbdd2ebb88da37c"
    },
```

Also, is this a good/bad idea?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `str` function converts an `ObjectId` to a string:

```
o = ObjectId()
print(str(o))
```

outputs

```
50c2852fa6165435b11ed7d7
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Mongoengine documentation I found that for their `{_id: {$oid: ''}}` scheme, they have a field called 'id'. So I needed:

```
<a href="/edit/{{ doc['id'] }}">
```